# OpenCV C++ imgdecode generating an exception on OSX

Tags: c++, image, macos, opencv, decoding

I have an application that takes pictures from the camera, encode them, do some stuff and then decode them. It works on Ubuntu, but on OSX `imgdecode` is generating the following exception:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.2.0) /tmp/opencv-20200404-3398-7w1b75/opencv-4.2.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:732: error: (-215:Assertion failed) buf.checkVector(1, CV_8U) > 0 in function 'imdecode_'

Abort trap: 6
```

I tried to encode and decode the image in the same script to have a minimal verifiable example. The script is the following:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include<unistd.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture cam(0);
    std::vector<uchar> buf_in;
    u_char *buf ;
    while(1)
    {
        cam>>frame;
        imencode(".png",frame, buf_in);
        //encode image and put data into the vector buf
        frame  = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(3, buf_in.size(), CV_8UC3, buf_in.data()), 1);
        imshow("window", frame);
        waitKey(2);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

and it is still generating the exception on OSX. Why is that? Why is the exception generated? Why only on OSX?

**POST SCRIPTA**

If one needs to compile the code, the following Makefile can be used:

```
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -pg
INC_PATH = `pkg-config --cflags opencv4`

LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv4`

SOURCEDIR := ./
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJDIR=$(SOURCEDIR)/obj

OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.d,$(SOURCES))
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

.PHONY: all clean

all: openCV

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) openCV

openCV: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_PATH) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

-include $(DEPENDS)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_PATH) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this, so I'll ask! 1) Why would you read an image, convert it unnecessarily to an in-memory PNG and then convert it back to a `Mat`? 2) Why do you instantiate a `Mat` from the buffer to decode - surely you can just pass the `buf_in` vector without making a `Mat` of it? 3) Maybe you could instantiate your `Mat` for the `imdecode()` on a separate line first then pass the result to `imdecode()` on the next line so we can see if the error is in instantiating the `Mat` or in decoding it?

Comment: 1) The code is just a [mcve] to show my problem in a more complex situation. The original program is a client server-application: the image is encoded on the server side, sent to the client as raw data, then decoded and shown. 2) do you mean `frame = imdecode(buf_in)`? I can try it. 3) I'll try that too, good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved changing the argument of `imdecode` to be a `vector<u_char>` containing the raw data, instead of initialising a new `Mat` structure.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include<unistd.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture cam(0);
    std::vector<uchar> buf_in;
    u_char *buf ;
    while(1)
    {
        cam>>frame;
        imencode(".png",frame, buf_in);
        //encode image and put data into the vector buf
        buf_out.assign(buf_in.data, buf_in.data+buf_in.size());
        frame  = cv::imdecode(buf_out, 1);
        imshow("window", frame);
        waitKey(2);
    }
    return 0;

}
```